# How can I create a scatter-plot of 2 factors, but only including rows based on another column?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataset, scatter-plot

This code produces a lovely scatterplot between two columns of my data, with datapoints and smoother:

```
ggplot(RPSdata, aes (x=RPSdata$Personal.Risk, RPSdata$Survival.Ten.Year)) +
geom_point(size = 1.5, shape = 1) +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, color="darkgrey", linetype = "solid", fill="lightgrey")
```

I would now like to remodel the same plot, but only including rows which are coded as '`1`' in column `Survival.Complete.Sense`.

I have tried the following code, and it produces the plot with smoother, but doesn't plot the actual datapoints for some reason:

```
ggplot(data = subset(RPSdata, Survival.Complete.Sense == 1) +
mapping = aes(x = Personal.Risk, y = Survival.Ten.Year)) +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, color="darkgrey", linetype = "solid", fill="lightgrey") + 
geom_point(size = 1.5, shape = 1)
```

It gives me: `Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?`

Is anyone able to help me to sort this out, either by adding datapoints successfully to the 2nd code or selecting the data by the secondary factor in the first code?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Any way you can provide an example of your data using `dput(head(df))` or another way? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try: `ggplot(data = subset(RPSdata, Survival.Complete.Sense == 1), mapping = aes(x = Personal.Risk, y = Survival.Ten.Year)) + 
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, color="darkgrey", linetype = "solid", fill="lightgrey") +
geom_point(size = 1.5, shape = 1)`

Comment: @Peter Thank you! Where exactly did I go wrong?

Comment: You separated the `mapping` argument from the `ggplot()` function and were treating it as a separate ggplot layer. The general pattern is ggplot(data, aes, other stuff) + geom_...